# Systemd Bash script daemon causes timeout and fails

Tags: bash, shell-script, systemd, daemon, systemd-unit

I have a service file: Memory.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Memory Service

[Service]
ExecStart=%h/opt/bin/Memory --quiet
SyslogIdentifier=MemoryService

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

It starts a bash script known as Memory, which calculates free memory percentage every 10 seconds and if its below certain level it kills firefox.

So, my bash script basically acts like a deamon and is supposed to run in the background without exiting.

When, I run this systemd service, the service always exist with timeout

```bsh
$ systemctl --user start Memory
Job for Memory.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
```

How to run this script in the background continuously? I want to start it with boot as mentioned in the service file.

---

Note: I am successfully able to run the script by myself on a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You may facing this issue because your script needs more time to run.

The default values is 90 sec.

> `DefaultTimeoutStartSec=` and `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=` default to 90s.

Try to add `TimeoutStartSec` to your config services, and input more than 90s depends on your scripts.

For the references: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: I want it to run forever till shutdown.